# Jacob's Video Game fix

Tags: lateral-thinking

Jacob would not stop playing video games no matter what his father said. Angry at Jacob's disobedience, the father decided he could fix the problem permanently with a hammer and a little elbow grease. To Jacob's dismay, he could no longer play video games however his father could. What happened?

Comment: This seems *way* too open-ended.  The simplest solution is that his father smashed all of his fingers with the hammer, though I doubt that's the solution that you're aiming at.  Open-ended lateral-thinking questions don't tend to fare well on this site, since they don't have one *demonstrably correct* answer, or criteria for deciding which answer is *most correct*.

Comment: Hmm... sorry but at least try to answer this question if your answer is satisfactory, then also i will mark it as correct. (Atleast if it makes some sense)

Comment: And what will you do if there are 6 other people whose answers are also "satisfactory"?  You can't mark them all correct.  Thus the need for **one** demonstrably correct answer, or a method of *ranking* answers to determine which is *objectively* the best.  With a question like this, neither of those is feasible, and thus this question is not a good fit for this site.

Comment: sorry I am closingn the question

Answer (score 1):

I think

> Assuming Jacob is small child who cannot lift hammer. Jacobs father keeps hammer on top of video game remote so that Jacob can no longer use the remote but his father can.

Comment: Don't forget to hide your answer using the ">!" tag!

Comment: Nice try! but by the sense that Jacob is mature enough to play video games using remotes and consoles,he is old enough to at least displace the hammer.

Comment: ^ that should be a specified detail in the question

Comment: please vote to close the question

Answer (score 1):

1) Jacob is:

> Blind

So the father:

> Who is not blind, destroyed the sound system (and whatever mechanism Jacob used to help him play).  So the father can see, and play, but Jacob cannot.

2) Similar to @Komal's answer:

> Jacobs father is Thor.  Thor places Mjolnir on the control or in some way to prevent Jacob from playing (Jacob is not worthy).

3) Or maybe:

> Jacob's video game console was destroyed, but the father's, which is password protected, was not.

Comment: please vote to close the question

Answer (score 1):

The answer is

> The father used the hammer to install a shelf high up on the wall. He then placed the video game console and the controllers up on the shelf out of Jacob's reach.